# For Loop Second Parameter Confusing

Tags: javascript, for-loop, boolean

I am working on code from Code Golf, and was compacting a script that finds two prime numbers whose sum is an integer selected by the user.

```
a=prompt();function b(n){for(i=2;i<n;i++)if(n%i<1)return;return 1}for(c=2,r=1;c<a&&r;c++)if(b(c)&&b(a-c))alert(a+": "+c+" + "+(a-c)),r=0
```

I tried changing the first for loop to:

```
for(i=2;1;i++)
```

But this broke the code. It turns out that `for(i=2;true;i++)` also will not work. But `i<n` yields `true`. Why is it that I can have `i<n` but not `true`?

Comment: `i<n` is evaluated on every iteration. If you put `true` then it's simply `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not put any value at all! This will work,

```
for(i=2;;i++)
```

**EDIT** Your assertion is not true. The expression `i<n` yields false when the loop must terminate.

```
for (i=2;;i++) {
  if (i >= n) break; // <-- Added break, and inverted the test.
  // as before....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i<n` only yields true when `i` is less than `n`. Since your loop increments `i` every time through the loop, `i` will eventually not be less than `n`, and then the loop will stop.